# What effect does music have on dogs?

Tags: dogs, psychology

I just had one experiment with some puppies.

I tried to play a flute and what I found was that the first time puppy barked at me. They probably think "what is this guy doing? Let's bark and let's make him leave our peaceful environment..." :P

But then at times, after the 3rd day, they run towards me and recognize me, that this is the guy who always comes with flute... They wag their tales and play around me.

Is it that like dogs like music?

I am wondering about exactly what happens when they hear my music. My street dogs becomes excited hearing my tune and runs like mad to come to me. I am actually very happy seeing them loving me like that.

Is it that music makes a pet more careful and peaceful? Because they start sleeping near me. Some times they try to sleep on my feet.

Does A Dog like or enjoy music like us? or they are just feeling "ok, it is you, I know" kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Dogs like certain types of music and get agitated by other types.

From Psychology Today:

> "The kind of music that the dogs listened to made a difference. When the researchers played heavy metal music, the dogs became quite agitated and began barking. Listening to popular music, or human conversation, did not produce behaviors that were noticeably different from having no sound at all. Classical music, on the other hand, seemed to have a calming effect on the dogs. While listening to it, their level of barking was significantly reduced and the dogs often lay down and settled in place. Wells summarized her findings saying, "It is well established that music can influence our moods. Classical music, for example, can help to reduce levels of stress, whilst grunge music can promote hostility, sadness, tension and fatigue. It is now believed that dogs may be as discerning as humans when it comes to musical preference."

Regarding the flute, Psychology Today says:

> "The kind of human music that most often induces a dog to howl is produced on wind instruments, particularly reed instruments, such as clarinets or saxophones."

Answer (score -4):

Dogs have an uncanny ability to recognize specific sounds - in fact, I would bet they are recognizing your flute being played by you and associating that with you. Try playing a different flute and see if they can tell the difference! My dog knows the sound of my van, and it sounds exactly like all the other vans on this street, to me.

I am not a professional but I think they associate the sounds with you and your presence. I don't think they 'enjoy' music like we do, and I don't think they are interested in it, other than what individuals associate with the sound.

They would want to sleep with you regardless of the music. We don't have a control group, almost all dogs like to sleep with their owners, it's a primal instinct for them. So, we can't test your last idea.